# Python lambda return syntax

Tags: python, lambda

Need some help with this code, can't figure the lambda syntax right here:

```
def func(m,n):
   if m < n:
      return ____
   elif m==n:
      return ____
   else:
      return ____
```

input:

```
func(3,10)()()()()()()
func(3,7)()()()
func(4,4)()
func(10,5)()()
func(9,5)()()
```

output should be:

```
13
m==n
m==n
15
14
```

I've tried:

```
def func(m, n):
    if m < n:
        return lambda: func(m+1, n-1)
    elif m == n:
        return lambda: print("m == n")
    else:
        return lambda: print(n+m)
```

This function works without errors with main like that:

```
func(3,10)()()()()() # ()
func(3,7)()()()
func(4,4)()
func(10,5)() # ()
func(9,5)() # ()
```

There is a way to make it work **with** the commented brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `lambda` returns `None`, and so when you try to call the return value (which is what happens when you do `f()()`) you're trying to call `None`.

If you want to be able to call the return value of a function, and call *that* return value, et cetera, an arbitrary number of times, `lambda` is not a great tool, because it can't return a reference to itself.  An object that implements `__call__` makes it fairly straightforward, though:

```
class InfiniteCallable:
    def __init__(self, msg = None):
        self.msg = msg

    def __call__(self):
        if self.msg is not None:
            print(self.msg)
            self.msg = None
        return self

def func(m,n):
   if m < n:
      return InfiniteCallable(m+n)
   elif m==n:
      return InfiniteCallable("m == n")
   else:
      return func(n, m)
```

Note that `InfiniteCallable.__call__(self)` returns `self`, meaning that every time you call an `InfiniteCallable` it returns a reference to itself, which you can therefore call again, repeating that process an infinite number of times.  The `self.msg` attribute allows it to print the message on the *first* call but not on each repeated call.

Comment: Thanks!
Do you think there is an option to summarize all of that in one line lambda expression?

Comment: Lambda is not a good tool for this.  It's possible, but extremely ugly, especially if the `print` needs to be in there too.  Maybe if you explain your use case more there's a better alternative -- why do you need to repeatedly call the return value in the first place?

Comment: It's just a sample to understand better the lambda different uses. So I understand what you wrote and I'll definitely do it that way if I'll be needed, just want to get know the lambda syntax in cases like that. 

Comment: This is *not a good use for lambda*.  I can't stress that enough.  :)  But it's not a good use case for *anything* -- there's no reason at all to just keep sticking `()()()()` on the end of every function call.  If you want to learn more about what lambda expressions are good for, I suggest googling "python lambda tutorial" so you can work with some better examples.